# Doctrine - delete data from table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a class, let's say CoreDoctrine.php, and a function inside it that will be used to delete a record from a table, here's the code

```
public function delete($entityManager, $objek){
        $entityManager->remove($objek);
        $entityManager->flush();
        $entityManager->clear();
        echo "\n\n Data berhasil dihapus \n\n";

    }
```

where the $objek is the entity that i want to erase, and $entityManager parameter is the object of Doctrine's EntityManager that is returned from a function

and then i run this code in the index.php like this

```
$doctrine = new CoreDoctrine();
$em = $doctrine->instantiateEntities();  //this function returns the EntityManager object

$doctrine->delete($em, $luki);  //where $luki is the entity object
```

when i execute the code, no error showed, but the data was not deleted from the database....
am i missing something??

update : here is the insinstantiateEntities() function :)

```
public function instantiateEntities(){
        $paths = array(__DIR__."/src");
        $isDevMode = false;

        // the connection configuration
        $dbParams = array(
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user'     => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'dbname'   => 'apbo2',
        );

        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
        $entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

        return $entityManager;
    }
```

Comment: show us the code of `instantiateEntities`. Also consider using Symfony2 service to inject `EntityManager` ;)

Comment: i've update the question. that's the instantiateEntities() :))

Comment: I see. Is there any particular reason why you're instantiating `EntityManager` all by yourself? :) I mean, Symfony2 did that for you ...

Comment: Yeah why don't you call, from a controller, `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` ?

Comment: hmm.. i'm just trying to put all together inside one class... is that a wrong way to do that?

Comment: ooow i got it now.. i tried to create a new file and not using function or instantiateEntities() anymore.. symfony already did that for me..thanks a lot :))